# Jenkins schedules 3 builds on first build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am creating a build that has 3 (sub builds) using the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) to fire the builds I need built in a specific order.

The main build is using the [Jenkins GIT plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) to monitor the repos I need so it can be triggered by a push to the branch I've declared.

The thing is, when I create the build at first (This is done through [autojenkins](https://github.com/txels/autojenkins)) and trigger it to build, it builds but then in the middle of the first build a second build is scheduled and in the middle of the seconds build a third build is then scheduled, effectively building the same project 3 times in a row, although there has been no changes to the repos.

The reasons for build 2 and 3 are the same: `Started by an SCM change` but there is nothing to see in the polling log.

Can this behaviour be explained somehow?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here's some info on Jenkins:
Jenkins v 1.529 running on Ubuntu 12.04 on Amazon
Jenkins GIT plugin v 1.5.0
Parameterized Trigger Plugin v 2.20